# "It feels so good when you solve a problem that at some point you found it impossible." Does this make sense?

Tags: grammaticality, translation

I am not a native english speaker and i want to know if the sentence is correct.

Comment: Yes. But the second "it" is redundant (and ungrammatical); thus ". . . a problem that at some point you found impossible."

Answer (score 2):

It's ok but seems lengthy. You could convey the same point in a shorter sentence

“It feels so good to solve a problem that at one point seemed impossible."